# Remove trailing space when using '' in excel column

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I want to take data from a spreadsheet and move it into a SQL Server query. The data in the spreadsheet so far is just positive numbers like 1643256. I inserted a column before and after with the value '', which puts a single quote before and after, and on the last column commas. I plan on copying and pasting the 4 columns so I can put all the data in a "where in()" clause. However when I do this the copy paste always has trailing space. How in Excel do I remove it as the function Trim doesn't seem to work with '' value?

Comment: Write an excel macro that reads each cell value and appends it to a comma delimited string.  If you need quotes, add them.  Use that string in your query.

Comment: It sounds like you're pasting the value directly into a statement then executing it. Once risk with dynamic SQL is SQL injection. I would instead create a variable, assign the value to the variable, trim the variable and have it in the query.

Also, are you intentionally looking for the string 4?

Comment: Is the comparison field a numeric type? If so, why add the single quotes - you don't need them.  That said, add the following formula in the topmost cell to the right of your first number. I will assume that your first number is in column A2. `="'" & A2 & "',"`. Copy that cell, and paste it down that column to the end. This will give you your formatted list, which you can then just copy and paste into SSMS (or wherever you need it.)

Comment: the comparison field is varchar(14)

Answer (score 0):

In another column I put as proposed from the comment by @LaughingVergil :

```
="'" & A1 & "',"
```

A1 can be what ever cell you are referring to. After you press enter, you can go to that cell and copy it. Now whatever other cells you paste it into, excel will apply the same formula but update the cell to the corresponding cell number you are pasting into, so for example if you paste in E8 it will update the formula to A8, pretty intuitive.